# Replace number format to k/M (SI prefixes) in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to get as an output instead of 10200 to see 10.2k, the same for millions etc. Is there any package which enables that transform with some customization?

Comment: You can roll your own `prettyprint` modelled after: https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/255854d004b55410f711bc07f8488ebf4597ad54/src/trials.jl#L279C13-L279C13

Comment: There's also https://painterqubits.github.io/Unitful.jl/stable/

Comment: hey, thank you for your inputs; it looks like creating my own function is the only solution as of now